# あなたの質問にまつわる「最高の」裏話

Tags: 討議

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝します。

---

スタック・オーバーフローでの質問は、氷山の一角にすぎません。例えシンプルな質問のように見えたとしても、私が思うには、その質問を投稿するまでには問題を解決するための辛い検索や長い一連の失敗した取り組み（そして時には上司とのやっかいなやりとり等）があったのではないでしょうか。例えば、私は過去にプロダクション用のサーバーを `rm -rf . /*` コマンドで削除（ドットとスラッシュの間にスペースが入るというタイポ）してしまい、そのような背景ストーリーから「[rm コマンドでの打ち間違いを防ぐには？](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6)」という質問が生まれました。

9月の間、Stack Overflow日本語版では[皆さんの質問にまつわる裏話](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3075/78)を募集していました。

素晴らしいストーリーを共有してくれた @nekketsuuu、投票してくれた方々、そして「参加したいけれど何か良いストーリーはないものか」と模索してくれた皆さんにも、感謝を申し上げます！コンテスト結果は、最高（そして唯一無二の =) ）ストーリー「[圧縮ファイルの展開をundoしたい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3081/78)」が優勝です。おめでとうございます！

MSEでのコンテストに関する投稿：“[What is the story behind your question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334861/314875)”

スタック・オーバーフローでの秋のコンテストは終了しましたが、引き続きあなたの質問にまつわる裏話を募集したいと思います。[日本語の方はスタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3075/78)そして[英語の方はMSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334861/314875)でストーリーを共有してくださいね。どうぞお気軽に。